# I got this error when I tried to run my app in android studio. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Circular dependency between the following tasks:

```
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug 
\--- :app:instantRunMainApkResourcesDebug
     \--- :app:transformClassesAndDexWithShrinkResForDebug
          \--- :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
               +--- :app:preColdswapDebug
               |    \--- :app:incrementalDebugTasks
               |         +--- :app:transformClassesAndClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug
               |         |    \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
               |         |         \--- :app:checkManifestChangesDebug (*)
               |         \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug (*)
               \--- :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
                    +--- :app:preColdswapDebug (*)
                    \--- :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug (*)

(*) - details omitted (listed previously)
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       debuggable true
    }
    customDebuggableBuildType {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

I tried to change from debuggable true to false then it works but cannot do a debugging
Thx in advance

Comment: post your `build.gradle` please

Comment: @shizhen I already added.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you have circular dependencies between tasks, so, try to find those two tasks. If you want other to check those tasks, you have to post your complete `build.gradle`, not just a part of it.

Comment: disable instant run in studio setting > build, execution,deployment > Instant run

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that is shown when you add 2 views inside a `RelativeLayout` while the first one depends on the second one and the second one depends on the first one. For example, when you put the first view `toRightOf="@+id/secondView"` secondView and the second view `toRightOf="@+id/firstView"` first view, then this will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your below two gradle tasks depends on each other.

```
:app:checkManifestChangesDebug 
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
```

But, this is NOT allowed in Gradle build system. You should remove this circular dependency.

One simpler solution is to disable your **instant run** feature, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/#disable-ir